# What is бойло? Is it an object?

Tags: значения

Leskov's book about the left-handed guy has this passage, when he visits an English factory:

> Всякий работник у них постоянно в сытости, одет не в обрывках, а на
>   каждом способный тужурный жилет, обут в толстые щиглеты с железными
>   набалдашниками, чтобы нигде ноги ни на что не напороть; работает не с
>   бойлом, а с обучением и имеет себе понятия.

What is a бойло?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В словаре Даля [упоминается](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/209902) диалектное слово:

> **Бойло** ср., курск. битва, драка, побоище, пошибанье.

Таким образом "работает не с бойлом, а с обучением" - т.е. работника не бьют а учат.
Левша был из Тулы. От Тулы до Курска 300 километров, так что Левша вполне может употреблять диалектные слова Курской губернии.

---

Looks like it is a dialect word. Dahl's dictionary [explains](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/209902) it as "битва, драка, побоище, пошибанье". So the meaning of the phrase is that the workers are not beaten. Левша is from Tula, which is only 300 kilometers away from Kursk where this word was recorded by Dahl.

Comment: Thanks, that makes ample sense. Looks like my original mistyped title ('abject' instead of 'object') was apposite after all :)